# Since dropping my iPod, I can only hear music, but no vocals

Tags: ipod-touch, audio

My iPod fell on the ground this morning. Since then, I can hear the music but not the singers anymore! It sounds as though they were in the next room during the recording. As I listen almost only to Podcasts, it's a real problem, because I almost hear nothing except jingles...

Has anyone a clue about the problem I'm facing? Is this a software or a hardware problem?

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29480/why-do-some-frequencies-get-cut-out

Comment: When you listen with headphones, try listening with each side (Left and right) individually.  Can you hear out of both of them?  Or just out of one ear?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like a Hardware problem with the *mini Jack*. Apparently one of  *rings* is not connecting properly, as if it was not fully plugged in. Make sure it is, try moving the mini Jack in circles and rotating, and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Also try different headphones.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Unfortunately it's the jack of your ipod which will need to be replaced or fixed. Doesnt cost much I think though.. about £20

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one of the stereo contact poles has become stuck.  To check this, play the same music on iTunes on your computer and move the left/right balance to to see if it sounds similar.

Over on *[this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/81889/9495)* answer, I explain how the headphones sockets physically work, and ways in which you can attempt to fix a temperamental one.